# Accessing an Array Variable From One Function in Another Function Within the Same Class

Tags: php

I have three functions within one class.

The function `listUpdates()` is supposed to `return $this->authors`;

How can I access this value in another function within the same class?

I'm attempting to access it in the function `get($id)`, but it keeps appearing as null, however, when I var_dump it in `listUpdates()`, it appears without any issue.

```
class AuthorInformation implements ObjectStore
{
    public $authors; 

    function path($arr, $path) {
        preg_match_all("/\['(.*?)'\]/", $path, $rgMatches);
        $rgResult = $arr;
        foreach($rgMatches[1] as $sPath)
        {
            $rgResult=$rgResult[$sPath];
        }
        return $rgResult;
    }

    //get the list of author updates
    public function listUpdates($url, $station, $daysOld)
    {
        // get the user params
        $this->url = $url;
        //var_dump("this is the url : " . $url . "<br/>");
        $this->station = $station;
        $this->daysOld = $daysOld;

        curl_init("");

        $wsUrl = $this->url . 'station_id=' . $this->station . '&days_changed=' . $this->daysOld . '&format=json';

        //curl stuff
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$wsUrl);
        $result=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $author_updates = json_decode($result, true);

        $root = "['response']['userprofiles']";
        $start = $this->path($author_updates, $root);

        //$authors = [];
        $this->authors = [];

        foreach ($start as $author) 
        {
            print $author['user_id'] . "<br>";
            $this->authors[$author['user_id']] = $author;
            // get the sharepoint author by this id
        }

        //var_dump($this->authors);
        return $this->authors;
    }

    //get a single author, based on their user_id
    public function get($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        var_dump("this is the user_id variable passed: ". $id);
        $this->authors = $authors;
        var_dump("<br/> this is the authors from listUpdates: " . $authors);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any call to `listUpdates` method from method `get`. Also, you're setting the property `$this->authors` to undefined variable `$authors` in the method `get`. It doesn't make a sense at all. Also, it's obvious that you're developing with error reporting disabled (or at least with disabled notices). That's very bad practice. Otherwise you would see your mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> public function get($id)
> {
>     $this->id = $id;
>     var_dump("this is the user_id variable passed: ". $id);
>     $this->authors = $authors;
>     var_dump("<br/> this is the authors from listUpdates: " . $authors);
> }
> ```

What you're *actually* doing in `get()` is setting $this->authors to the (as yet undefined) $authors variable. You probably want to replace that line with

```
$authors = $this->authors;
```

or just use `$this->authors` directly, rather than assigning it to a variable.

Comment: I just tried it and it still doesn't work. Is there perhaps something wrong with the way I am setting the array in the listUpdates() function?

Comment: The code you're using to set the authors property in `listUpdates()` is fine. You should `var_dump($this->authors)` in `get()` before you do anything else and see what you get.

Also, you probably don't want to `$this->id = $id;` in `get()` either.

Comment: I just tried `var_dump($this->authors);` and the result I get is `NULL`. I don't really get it, since the same var_dump in `listUpdates()` works fine.

Comment: Is it the same instance you're calling it on?

Answer (score 1):

You use `$this` to access properties and methods if the function is within the same class. If it is a static function you can use `self::` or `static::`.

For example:

```
<?php

class Car 
{
    private $name = 'Ford';

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getOutput()
    {
        return 'The car name is ' . $this->getName() . '.';
    }
}

?>
```

Make sure you are setting your properties too.